# Google Places API autocomplete not working for Hong Kong?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google's API has been serving well searching for cities within a given country. This happens server-side. However, for some reason it isn't finding *anything* in Hong Kong. For example, searching for Kowloon, a city in HK, returns an empty array. Here is the request:

```
GET /maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Kowloon&key=...&types=(cities)&components=country:hk
```

This request format works great for other countries. Why is it behaving differently for Hong Kong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though it's to do with the `(cities)` type restriction. I'm not sure why.

For example:

```
const options = {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'hk'},
    types: ['(cities)'],
}
```

does not work. But:

```
const options = {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'hk'},
}
```

does